# Only allow GET request with htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

How should I allow only GET request to access all the files and script from my server using htaccess?

My web server is Apache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may also want to have a look at the Apache [Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit) and/or [LimitExcept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept) directives.  Rewrite rules give you the opportunity to put up a custom error page though.

I believe something like this might work:

```
<LimitExcept GET HEAD>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: Already did when I realized I put it in all lower case.  :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
> RewriteRule ^.*$ /path/to
```

Comment: This will redirect non-GET requests to another path on the server; it doesn't 'disallow' them. Though you could redirect them to an error page and use the `[R=406]` on the end of the `RewriteRule` line.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST

working !